# Firebird pdf blob save as pdf-file by PHP

Tags: php, blob, firebird

I have a blob which we receive from a Firebird 3.0 database.

```
if($dbh = ibase_connect($db,$username,$password, 'UTF-8')){
echo "Connecton steht zur Firebird DB steht! <br>";
$sql = "SELECT MEMO FROM DMS where ID = '44'";
// Execute query
$rc = ibase_query($dbh, $sql);
// Get the result row by row as object
$data = ibase_fetch_object($rc);
$blob_data = ibase_blob_info($data->MEMO);
$blob_hndl = ibase_blob_open($data->MEMO);

$inhalt = ibase_blob_get($blob_hndl, $blob_data[0]);
```

With

```
ibase_blob_echo($data->MEMO)
```

there comes a lot of signs in browser, so the SQL query works. Now I'd like to write the content (its a PDF) in a pdf file on disk.

Every try didn't succeed:

```
file_put_contents('test.pdf', $inhalt);
file_put_contents('test.pdf', ibase_blob_echo($data->MEMO));
```

and much more.

When we try to open the PDF File with Acrobat Reader, there comes an error message: no PDF File / File-type is not supported

How can we fix this?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? Given your problem description I suspect it is a `blob sub_type text`, not a `blob sub_type binary`, which means the file will be corrupted.

Comment: maybe you should check the file content beginning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and there are programs for both UNIX and Windows which have their guessing databases. P.S. also do you close the BLOB handle?

Comment: People has to cut the prefix from the BLOB here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608810 Dunno if that is applied here

Comment: Most probably the blog is big, split into many segments, and you only download first segment of the file, deleting all the rest. See the comments at http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ibase-blob-get.php

Comment: @Arioch'The IIRC that question was about an application specific storage format, and not a general problem.

Comment: it seems funny that PHP has `ibase_blob_import` function but not `ibase_blob_export`. C - consistency :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your answers ... We interpreted them in a way, that the code above is basicly correct. After a while, we found out, that the error apears because we changed the charset in the DB Connect to UTF8 for the varchar Fields. For the blob we connect now without Charset change and the  readout work properly. Thank you again.

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($db,$username,$password)
```

Comment: That would indicate your blobs are sub_type text, not sub_type binary; you would need to fix that, instead of using a separate connection (and associated overhead).

Comment: w.r.t. "code correct" I wonder what is your maximum BLOB size... Try putting some 100MB zip file into the blob and then read it out using that simplified code. Will it ever work? Also, you did not say if you close blob handle or not. The leakage of handles is a known case of Firebird performance steady degradation.