# Display Blob content after fetching from firebird db

Tags: php, firebird

When I run the below query

```
select first 1 IMG from img_lib;
```

I get the output as 
IMG                             4cc:0
BLOB display set to subtype 1. This BLOB: subtype = 0

Can any one help me with a PHP code to display the blob content as an Image?
I don't think MySQL will work here, Can anyone help me with firebird query?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608810/displaying-blob-data-from-a-firebird-database-using-php) suggests it should be possible with `ibase_blob_echo`.

Comment: That question seems to be more about reverse-engineering application-specific internal format. But there indeed recently was a question, about reading multi-segment blobs.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304792/firebird-pdf-blob-save-as-pdf-file-by-php

Comment: See discussion in the comments at http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ibase-blob-get.php - the very page seems to only showcase the simpliest case of short blobs (1 segment only) then the users show more elaborate code in discussion.

Answer (score 2):

PHP offers two libraries to work with Firebird/Interbase databases: [Ibase](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.ibase.php) & [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php).

Ibase offer two ways to retrieve blobs.
One is using lazy loading with [ibase_blob_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-blob-get.php) function:

```
if (is_null($field)) return null;
$info = ibase_blob_info($field);
$handle = ibase_blob_open($field);
return ibase_blob_get($handle, $info[0]);
```

This way is good, when you need to fetch just some blobs, not all, as it is a costly operation.

Another way is to use `IBASE_TEXT` fetch flag parameter in [ibase_fetch_assoc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-assoc.php) function or fetch [object](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-object.php) / [row](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-fetch-row.php). It will return right in fetch result the blob content.

The second library, PDO with [Firebird](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php) driver, fetches blobs automatically.

Next after you have loaded BLOB content into memory, you need to output it as an image.
Here is a sample code, assuming you have a jpeg image format:

```
<?php
// fetch here blob content described in previous methods
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $blob_content;
```

Later point image source to your script like `<img src="blob_image.php" />`

Comment: will IBASE_TEXT return contents of big blobs, that exceed the VARCHAR size max limit (32KB AFAIR) ?

Comment: "Later point image source to your script" - or use data:// URI scheme :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The, as far as i know, yes, we store big blobs and retrieve them without problems. The PHP engine fetch entire blob content, if the memory permits :)

Comment: Great! I just was afraid the lib goes lazy way and modifies the SQL SELECT into something like  `...cast (blob-column-name as varchar(...) collate octet)...`

Comment: BTW, which of the two mentioned libraries do you actually use? It seems `ibase_blob_get` returns only the first segment of the blob, which might contain all the blob, but with larger blobs it might be different.

Comment: @Arioch'The, currently we use PDO. Patched some bugs and now it works well. Checked `ibase_blob_get` function, it allow to load big blobs in chunks ibase_blob_get(handle, size). Strange, at time we used ibase_ we loaded it in one call. PDO internally load the whole blob in chunks: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_firebird/firebird_statement.c#L253